# Cannot connect to sql server 2008 using JDBC

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I have tried all the methods to connect to the server.I am using `sql server 2008` on mixed authentication mode.I can login  via the sql server management studio using the sa login.But when I try accessing the same db from my java program I get the following error:

```
SQL Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:191d94bb-a55e-47a0-bb9f-b84638313cf4
```

This is my connectionstring:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String connectionUrl= "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Northwind;user=sa;password=sa;";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have accessed my database in the same way. One of my problems were that I hadn't enabled the port and IP for the database. Check these options in SQL Server Configuration Manager. Hope this helps =)